# How to read the alpha channel of a TIFF image in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, alpha, channel

I want to read the alpha channel from a tiff image using Python OpenCV. I am using Enthought Canopy with OpenCV 2.4.5-3 module.

I followed the OpenCV website's tutorial using cv2.imread, but it doesn't seem to work.

What I have now is:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('image.tif', -1)
```

Then I used: `print (image.shape)`, it still shows the (8192, 8192, 3). But I used Matlab to read the same image, I can see the dimension of this image is (8192, 8192, 4).

I am not sure what should I do to read the alpha channel of this image.

Thanks in advance!!
Nan

Comment: Not sure if following answer to ["Alpha channel in OpenCV"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1451021/2419207) is still relevant, but it may be: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2111434/2419207

Comment: Thanks, iljau! If the same image is PNG file, I can read it using cv2.imread and I can see there are 4 layers. But if the format is TIFF  which has the alpha channel (Matlab can show it), it only shows 3 layers. I am wondering why??

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but: ["OpenCV issue: alpha channel support for 8-bit tiffs (Patch #2791)"](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2791)

Comment: And not an answer to the question, but I have found .. https://github.com/luispedro/imread .. to be most the convenient method of converting images to numpy arrays.

Comment: Or [`scipy.ndimage.imread`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html#scipy.ndimage.imread), which uses [`PIL`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm) under covers.

Answer (score 17):

This is an old question, but just in case someone else stumbles on it: if img.tiff is a 4-channel TIFF, then

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('img.tiff', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print img.shape
```

yields (212,296,**4**) as expected.

If you then use

```
channels = cv2.split(img)
```

you can reference the alpha layer (`channels[3]`) - for instance, as a mask.

The idea for this was taken from [How do I use Gimp / OpenCV Color to separate images into coloured RGB layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213407/how-do-i-use-gimp-opencv-color-to-separate-images-into-coloured-rgb-layers) which cleverly uses a fake layer and `merge` to enable recovery of the individual RGB layers in their actual colours.

Comment: Tried the flag, still got 3 channels. My cv2 version is 2.4.9. Maybe it depends on cv2 build flags?

Tiff image was generated with Photoshop by adding channel "Alpha" to "Channels" tab. No transparency or layers were used, just background layer. Maybe it matters too.

Comment: Does Photoshop save the image as RGBA (i.e., specifically registering the layer named 'Alpha' as an actual alpha layer)? It would make sense if it didn't, since not every 4-channel image is RGBA. I often get images that have 4 layers (one named 'Alpha'), but need to be explicitly 'converted' to RGBA. In https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229758/gdal-python-api-warp-and-translate-struggling-with-rgba I had this issue, and wanted to avoid a 'convert to RGBA' step (takes ~60ms/image, but there are ~3m images... so it adds **stupid** amounts of time).

Comment: I don't have this option in CS4 (Image->Mode has nothing like "RGBA"). Also checked this thread - https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1587246, those guys are confused too. I had to save the files as Tiffs and use Xnview to batch convert them into Png (alpha becomes transparency that way) and use Png's in OpenCV. Also there's just nothing to work with at OpenCV, even internal vars contain only 3 channels and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution this problem in converting the original image to RBGA format through PIL library.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

path_to_image = 'myimg.png'
image = Image.open(path_to_image).convert('RGBA')
image.save(path_to_image)

image = cv2.imread(path_to_image, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print image.shape
```

out > (800, 689, 4)

Comment: PIL is what I am using now. But I was thinking if OpenCV can directly read RGBA image directly.

Answer (score -3):

I solved the same problem with:

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```

Comment: Do you mean that you have same problem and upgrading the OpenCV resolved it?

Comment: Yes, I found some comments say that "openCV 2.4" have some bug there. So this may improve.